# need to get Array elements in Tab delimited Form

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I tried to search answer however I could not find.

what i did is;

```
val a1 = sc.textFile("/home/Dataset/CSV/EMP4.csv") -- fine 

val emp4 = a1.map(x=>x.split(",")).map(x=>(x(0),x(1),x(4))).filter(x=>x._3 > "2000").sortBy(x=>x._1) ---> fine
```

When I did

```
val result = emp4.collect.mkString(" ")

its giving me result as 

String = (102,bMeena,5000) (103,cStevana,3000) (104,dMeenab,5000) (105,eStevanc,3000) (109,Meena,5000) (110,Stevana,5000) (111,Meenab,5000)
```

But My expectation is to get o/p as below;

```
((102 bMeena 5000),(103 cStevana 3000), (104 dMeenab 5000), (105 eStevanc 3000), (109 Meena 5000), (110 Stevana 5000), (111 Meenab 5000))
```

anything I am missing or need to correct ? please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change a little bit of your logic, i.e. instead of creating `Tuple3` you create `Array` and a little twist while creating the final string as

```
val a1 = sc.textFile("/home/Dataset/CSV/EMP4.csv")

val emp4 = a1.map(x=>x.split(",")).map(x=>Array(x(0),x(1),x(4))).filter(x=>x(2) > "2000").sortBy(x=>x(0))
val result = emp4.map(_.mkString("(", " ", ")")).collect.mkString(",")
```

and you should have your desired result as

```
//result: String = (102 bMeena 5000),(103 cStevana 3000),(104 dMeenab 5000),(105 eStevanc 3000),(109 Meena 5000),(110 Stevana 5000),(111 Meenab 5000)
```

If you don't want the result in string then you can omit the last `.mkString(",")` which should give you

```
val result = emp4.map(_.mkString("(", " ", ")")).collect
//result: Array[String] = Array((102 bMeena 5000), (103 cStevana 3000), (104 dMeenab 5000), (105 eStevanc 3000), (109 Meena 5000), (110 Stevana 5000), (111 Meenab 5000))
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thank you Ramesh ! its help.

instead of  doing val result = emp4.map(_.mkString("(", " ", ")"))

can we have something like \t to make the values tab delimited ?

Comment: I tried ..
val result = emp4.map(_.mkString("\t") 

And it worked